# CentOS 6 32bit - Firefox: Error: no display specified. How do i fix this?

Tags: firefox, centos, vps, centos6

I just bought a VPS from BlueVM.com i've never owned or used a VPS before.
I thought it would be an easy procedure since all i wanted it to do was run Mozilla firefox 24/7.
But it's harder than i though it'd be :/
After purchasing i went to the VPS control panela nd then to the command center, with some google search i managed to download & install firefox onto my VPS.
According to google all i had to do was type: firefox and it should launch.
As the title states above i got this: Error: no display specified
How do i fix this? I did some google search and found some people having this problem too, unfortunately the tutorials they provided were not noob-friendly :/
I didn't understand anything.
Please help me fix this problem guys :)

Another thing!
How would it be if i managed to launch firefox, would a firefox window just appear instead of the command center?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will only launched if you have desktop version. You are using VPS which is text based. You can't use firefox in minimal version.

Comment: Follow this link  http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Linux/LINUX_AddGNOMEToCentOSMinimalInstall.shtml                                                                                        Then You can install VNC server to access your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the experience of Travis CI and VMs.

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/firefox/

You can see the Firefox Command Line Option or Arguments  here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

You can share your problem here also:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/